# android: setting the drawableTop icon at its original location

Tags: android, button, layout

I have a button in the app that invoke a certain function, and before that, the system will check whether that specific function is available, if not, it will implement the following:

### XML:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_speak"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/purple_btn"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_headphones_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Listen!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

### Code:

```
                speakBtn.setEnabled(false);  
                speakBtn.setText("Speak NOT\nSUPPORTED");
                speakBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_btn);
                speakBtn.setTextSize(12);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                params.weight = 1;
                speakBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
                speakBtn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

### Outlook:

[image] Button: Enabled

[image] Button: Disabled (the wording should be Listen NOT supported...)

### Question:

Once the button becomes disabled, the background of the button is changed by using the `.setBakgroundResource` and then the button can have its background resources changed, yet the icon goes up!

How could set the icon to stay at where it orginally be, and just the background and the text on the button being changed? (at least the icon would not go up to that top of the button)

Thanks!

Comment: I think this happend bcz text length change in ur case you have to make two image and set as button background..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but my bet is that `padding` value may be erased when setting the new `LayoutParams`. You could easily check that by commenting out this line.-

```
speakBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If it works, you could try manually setting the padding after that line.-

```
speakBtn.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 0);
```

By the way, remember that should keep your `dimension` values stored in a dimens resources file (i.e. `dimens.xml`)

Comment: oh yes...I have implemented your suggestion and using 15, its moves the icon down a bit...maybe as Haresh points out, the length of the text becomes longer and distorted...I have randomly tried using real device and found out that it needs setPadding become 0, 25, 0, 0 can only then make the icon align top with the other buttons using the same setting.

Comment: Mmh it's also possible that `15` hardcoded are 15px and not 15dp. That's why you should have a dimen resource and reference it as getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen15) for instance.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! i have followed by setting it in dimens resources! it really works!! Many thanks for your help!!